# why is this insertion into a heap faster than insertion into an unsorted list?

Tags: c++, list, data-structures, heap

After inserting 100000000 elements into my heap and unsorted list, it seems that the heap insertion is actually faster (12 seconds vs 20 seconds). Why is this? I believe heap insertion is `O(logn)` while unsorted list insertion is `O(1)`. I also noticed that my heap insertion implementation doesn't actually scale with the number of inputs. This also confuses me.

Here is the code that I ran:

```
int main ()
{
    clock_t unsortedStart;
    clock_t heapStart;

    double unsortedDuration;
    double heapDuration;

    int num_pushes = 100000000;
    int interval = 10000;

    ofstream unsorted ("unsorted.txt");
    ofstream heap ("heap.txt");

    UnsortedPQ<int> unsortedPQ; 
    HeapPQ<int> heapPQ; 

    unsortedStart = clock();

    for (int i = 0; i < num_pushes; ++i)
    {
        if (i % interval == 0) {
            unsortedDuration = ( clock() - unsortedStart ) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
            unsorted << unsortedDuration << " " << i << endl;
        }

        unsortedPQ.insertItem(rand() % 100);
    }

    heapStart = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < num_pushes; ++i)
    {
        if (i % interval == 0) {
            heapDuration = ( clock() - heapStart ) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
            heap << heapDuration << " " << i << endl;
        }
        heapPQ.insertItem(rand() % 100);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the heap implementation of insert (uses `std::vector`):

```
template <class T>
void HeapPQ<T>::insertItem(T data) { 
    //insert into back of heap (std::vector)
    dataArray.push_back(data);
    int i = dataArray.size() - 1;

    //sifts the inserted element up
    while (i != 0 && dataArray[(i - 1) / 2] > dataArray[i]) {
        swap(dataArray[i], dataArray[(i - 1) / 2]);
        i = (i - 1) / 2;
    }
}
```

This is the unsorted list implementation of insert (uses `std::list`):

```
//pushes element to the back of a std::list
template <class T>
void UnsortedPQ<T>::insertItem(T data) { dataList.push_back(data); }
```

Comment: Vectors use a single contiguous memory block. Modern hardware is really very, very good at accessing and scanning through a consecutive chunk of RAM.

Comment: Are you running this on something that can be parallelized/has multiple cores? If that is the case then it is possible the OS level is optimizing it by viewing everything as a contiguous block of memory.

Comment: @OmegaNalphA Yes, my machine has multiple cores. But regardless, heap insertion should take longer as number of elements gets larger but this doesn't seem to happen.

Comment: Never underestimate how long it can take to execute that single iteration in O(1) if the conditions are unfavourable.

Comment: The difference is probably the amount of allocations: while `std::list` is probably allocating on every `push_back` `std::vector` is growing its internal array exponentially using only a logarithmic amount of allocations (or potentially a single one, when properly initialised). Also avoid expensive operations for timing: instead of writing to a file every `1000` inserts, store your raw timings in a preallocated array and process that array after your run - also warm up your caches! To see what I mean: try inverting the order of `unordered` and `heap` and you'll probably get a different result.

Comment: @everett, can you try running the experiment for bigger number range? upto INT_MAx may be?

Comment: Remove the interval timing code from the loop. Just get the starting clock before starting the loop, and the ending clock after. The interval timing is probably skewing your results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The insertion into the heap is `O(logn)`, that mean every insertion could take at most `O(logn)` steps. It does not mean it has to.

In your example average cost of inserting an element is `O(1)`. Why that?

For simplicity, let's assume you insert only `0`a and `1`s in a random order (in your current version only numbers `0..99` (`rand() % 100`) are inserted - the calculation is more complex, but the behavior stays the same). After `2*n` elements are inserted, there would be about `n` `0`s and `n` `1`s in the heap,  and the heap would look as follows:

```
                                 0
                                0 0
                               00 00
                          ...............
                         0 0 0  0  0  0  0
                       11 11 11 11 11 11 11
```

So basically, `1`s are all at the last level `k` and `0`s are at levels `0..k-1`.

1. if `1` is inserted, there is nothing to do (there are no `2`s above).
2. if `0` is inserted there is at most one swap (`1`s may be in the level above the last level, but 2 levels above).

That meas in average we need only `0.5` swaps and not `k`.

Having the same asymptotic running time, it is all down to the (amortized) costs for inserting in a vector and in a list. The list seems to be slower (my assumption would be, that for every insert it needs to allocate an element on the heap via `new` and this is a quite slow operation. The costs depend on other factors, e.g. the size of the inserted objects, and thus it may vary which one is faster).

---

Let's take a closer look at your case, where the numbers are generated by a uniform dstribution `[0..99]`. After `n>>100` insertions we will have the following situation (there is some hand-waving involved, but the gist should be clear):

1. the last level (`k`-th) of the heap has `n/2` elements and consists of numbers `50..99`. So for 50% of possible numbers (i.e. `50..99`) no shift is needed.
2. the second last level (`k-1`-th)  of the heap has `n/4` elements and consists of numbers `25..49`. That means for 25% of possible numbers exactly 1 shift is needed.
3. the level `k-2`  has `n/8` elements and consists of numbers `13..24`.
4. The levels above `log 100/log 2` have only `0`s inside. So the maximal number of shifts possible is `m=log 100/log 2`, independent of `n` - the number of elements in the heap.

So worst case costs for the insertion would be `log 100/log 2`, the average costs are even smaller:

```
E(insertion)=0*1/2+1*1/4+2*1/8+...<=1.0
```

i.e. on average we have less than 1 shift per insertion.

NB: It does not mean, that inserting in the heap has amortized costs of `O(1)` - if you would insert the numbers not in random order, but first all `99`s, then `98`s, ..., then `0`s you would have costs of `O(log n)` per insertion.

Comment: So your saying most of my inserts only cost constant time or very little swapping? I still don't see how this could be the case because a random number between 0 and 99 has a good chance of sifting up a significant portion of the heap, making a lot of the insertions O(logn) does it not? I can see why it wouldn't in your case because you only consider 1s and 0s but if there are 100 possibilities there should be more swapping.

Comment: I tried to make my answer more explicit about the range 0..100. You have always the option to count the number of shifts  in your experiments in order to see, whether the average costs are `O(1)` or not.

Comment: Great answer! By the way, Wikipedia agrees that a binary heap has O(log n) insertion. While the big-O notation is much abused by programmers, the article explicitly states that this indicates an upper bound (as opposed to the "tight bound" big theta notation), i.e. worst case. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29#Comparison_of_theoretic_bounds_for_variants