insertion to binary heap gets faster as the size of the heap gets larger?
offer() in PriorityQueue seems to execute faster as the size of the queue gets larger.
Test Results
I implemented a min heap in java, and I wanted to test the time complexity of insertion to it. The results were very weird, as it seemed like insertion is faster when the heap is bigger, although the number of swaps (swims) is greater.
I thought there might me a bug in my implementation, so I tried PriorityQueue in the JCF, and to my surprise, the results were the same!
Here's the test I wrote to calculate time.
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PriorityQueue<Double> p = new PriorityQueue<>(200000000); //capacity: 200 Million
    
    int n = 100000000;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        p.offer(100 + Math.random() * 10000);
    }
        
    int numOfInsertions = 5;
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    
    p.offer(Math.random() * 100); //inserted elements are less than all elements
    p.offer(Math.random() * 100);//in the heap, to ensure a full swim all the way up
    p.offer(Math.random() * 100);//to the root
    p.offer(Math.random() * 100);
    p.offer(Math.random() * 100);
    
    long end = System.nanoTime();
    
    System.out.println((end - start)/numOfInsertions);
    
    System.out.println(p.peek()); //ensure that the elements less than 100
                                  //were inserted
}


There is a good debate in here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47257045/why-is-this-insertion-into-a-heap-faster-than-insertion-into-an-unsorted-list

I hope you did about 10 seconds of warm-up, including at least 1'000'000 runs of that test before taking the times? Java speeds up a lot during execution. If you have not done the warmup, your tests will be completely off and any result confusing. So: 10 seconds warm-up, then let the test itself run 10 seconds, then calculate the times, then you'll get somewhere.

How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java
